# Load image on hover using span data-original

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So while I'm trying to update some styles, I've encountered the following problem: I cannot find and replace my `<span data-original='image.jpg'></span>` to `<img src='image.jpg' />` anymore.

My original worked fine (which only contained 1 `<span>` element):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.trigger').mouseover(function() {
   // find our span
   var elem = $(this).siblings('span');

    // get our img url
   var src = elem.attr('data-original');

    // change span to img using the value from data-original

   elem.replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '"/>');

  });

  $('.trigger').mouseout(function() {
   // find our span
   var elem = $(this).siblings('img');

    // get our img url
   var src = elem.attr('src');

    // change span to img using the value from data-original
   elem.replaceWith('<span data-original="'+src+'"></span>');
  });
});
</script>

<a href="profile.php" class="trigger" target="_self" id="al">Profile</a>
<span data-original="http://via.placeholder.com/140x100" /></span>
```

But changing the HTML to something with 2 span elements causes the above to fail (because it selects the 1st `<span>` instead of the 2nd)

```
<div class="tooltip"><a href="profile.php" class="trigger" target="_self" id="al">Profile</a>
<span class="tooltiptext"> <!-- tooltip with a table inside it -->
<table class="tg" style="table-layout: fixed;background: black;" >
<tr>
<th class="tg-su" colspan="2"><strong><i>My info</i></strong><hr></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-su"><span data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"></span></td>
<td class="tg-su">My personal description</td>
</tr>
</table>
</span> <!-- span from the tooltiptext class -->
</div>
```

An example can be found [**`HERE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/9xj8dywb/6/)

I only need to know how to easily select the 2nd span element and thus get the value of `data-original`.

**EDIT**

I found out that with copy-pasting one of my `</span>` didn't get copied (I noticed it after reading one of the answers). This `</span>` is supposed to be after the `</table>` tag, because the whole table is meant as tooltip (edited above). Maybe it was a good idea to provide the css with it, so you can find the updated script (combined with @Muhammad answer) [**`HERE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/9xj8dywb/9/)

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Please see the **edit** above.

Comment: updated the answer see **Edit** section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because you are finding the span with `data-original` in the siblings whereas in the siblings you have added a new `span.tooltiptext` which is not the span you previously used to detect the image source, you have moved it inside the `table`.

so you have to change the

```
var elem = $(this).siblings('span');
```

to

```
$(this).siblings('table').find('span[data-original]');
```

Same goes for retrieving the image back and hiding it

change

```
var elem = $(this).siblings('img');
```

to

```
var elem =  $(this).siblings('table').find('img');
```

Apart from the actual problem above you have invalid markup like unclosed `span.tooltiptext`

```
<span class="tooltiptext">
```

Then you have a `/` inside the `span` before the `</span>`

```
<span data-original="http://via.placeholder.com/140x100" /></span>
```

You can see a working demo here

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.trigger').on('mouseover', function() {
    // find our span
    var elem = $(this).siblings('table').find('span[data-original]');

    // get our img url
    var src = elem.attr('data-original');

    // change span to img using the value from data-original

    elem.replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '"/>');

  });

  $('.trigger').on('mouseout', function() {
    // find our span
    var elem = $(this).siblings('table').find('img');

    // get our img url
    var src = elem.attr('src');

    // change span to img using the value from data-original
    elem.replaceWith('<span data-original="' + src + '"></span>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="profile.php" class="trigger" target="_self" id="al">Profile</a>
<span class="tooltiptext"></span>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"><strong><i>My name</i></strong>
      <hr>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"></span></td>
    <td>My personal description</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## `EDIT`

As per your update in the question you should change the line

```
var elem = $(this).siblings('table').find('span[data-original]');
```

to

```
var elem = $(this).siblings('span').find('span[data-original]');
```

inside the `$('.trigger').on('mouseover', function() {`

and then change the line

```
var elem = $(this).siblings('table').find('img');
```

to

```
var elem = $(this).siblings('span').find('img');
```

inside the   `$('.trigger').on('mouseout', function() {`

See the Updated Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.trigger').on('mouseover', function() {
    // find our span
    var elem = $(this).siblings('span').find('span[data-original]');

    // get our img url
    var src = elem.attr('data-original');

    // change span to img using the value from data-original

    elem.replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '"/>');

  });

  $('.trigger').on('mouseout', function() {
    // find our span
    var elem = $(this).siblings('span').find('img');

    // get our img url
    var src = elem.attr('src');

    // change span to img using the value from data-original
    elem.replaceWith('<span data-original="' + src + '"></span>');
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-left: 6px solid #884fa1;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 125%;
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 5%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-color: purple;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.tg th {
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.tg .tg-su {
  border-color: inherit;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="tooltip"><a href="profile.php" class="trigger" target="_self" id="al">Profile</a>
    <span class="tooltiptext">
    <table class="tg" style="table-layout: fixed;background: black;" >
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-su" colspan="2"><strong><i>My info</i></strong><hr></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="tg-su"><span data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"></span></td>
    <td class="tg-su">My personal description</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm gonna try and play around with siblings some more to get a hang of it.

Comment: you re wlecome @Y.T

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery siblings method select the element siblings as mentioned [here](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) 
and your 2nd didn't work because there is no  "span" siblings for the class `.trigger` that has the `data-original` attribute the only siblings are

```
<span class="tooltiptext">
```

and

```
<table></table>
```

So if you want to select the span that has the `data-original` attribute you have to replace
`var elem = $(this).siblings('span');`
 by 
`var elem = $(this).siblings('table span[data-original]');`